# Regular Expression to match when element locations change

Tags: regex

I need to match this and extract the value from these tags.  Problem is they are generated dynamically and someone decided to switch things up each time the page is refreshed.

So the tag could be this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="838218230" name="vstablepid_2717_1State">
```

or this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vstablepid_2717_1State" value="838218230" >
```

I can do each one separately, with something like this:

```
value="(.+?)".*"vstable
```

Is there one statement that can to both?

---

Ideas so far:

Using some type of optional syntax i could say find the 'vstable' match either before or after the value - but I still need to find at least one 'vstable' on the line.

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? Which attribute? All of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a look ahead to assert `vstable`, then grab your content (from the group):

```
<(?=[^>]*vstable[^>]*>)[^>]*value="(.*?)"[^>]*>
```

The look-ahead part of the regex `(?=...)` is requiring that `vstable` appear before the next `>`

Comment: This also matches `<bork>vstable<foo value="bar">`.  I would include the tag name (`input`), and use `[^>]*` and `"([^"]*)"` instead of `.*?` and `"(.*?)"` to keep the match confined within the one tag.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yeah. I almost did that, but I see now I have to. Thx. I waived the replacement of `"(.*?)"` though, since if that fails, the XML is garbage anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `or` together both statements?

```
(?:value="(.+?)".*"vstable)|(?:"vstable.*?value="(.+?)")
```

Or am I missing something?

*Edit*: There's a caveat to this method - sometimes the value will appear in the first capturing group and sometimes in the second. Bohemian's answer is better (also) in this regard.

Comment: I'm just a regex newbie, so you're not missing anything!

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex:

```
value="(.+?)".*"vstable
```

Is enforcing the fact that `vstable` occurs after `value`.

You can simply take out that part and simply have it be:

```
value="(.+?)"
```

For most regex compilers, `.+?` should be non-greedy and will stop matching when it reaches the closing quote `"`.  That way, wherever `value` occurs, it'll be picked up.

But that depends on your need, and whether you specifically want to pick the `value` at the line where `vstable` occurs, but that wasn't specified in the question, so I'm giving a generic answer.

Comment: Then first match the lines with `vstable` in them, THEN match the `value` from those lines... do them separately in that order.  Or use @mgibsonbr's approach of `or`ing their placements.